# Derive tempo value from the unit pattern length

Tags: time-signatures, tempo

A guitar instrumental music was played with 4/4 timing and tempo of 86 bpm settings. One pattern consist of 6 notes ( or beats). On audacity, a unit strumming pattern ( = 1 bar)  takes roughly 2.78sec. How do I derive the bpm theoretically from this pattern length correctly? Or in other words how do I get a figure close to 86bpm from this unit pattern length of 2.78 (approx) sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's given that one measure lasts 2.78 seconds.

Since one measure lasts 2.78 seconds, there can be 60/2.78 measures per minute.

It's also given there are four beats per measure. Since there are four beats per measure, the tempo is (60 / 2.78) * 4 bpm.

Therefore, the tempo is approximately 86.33 bpm.